# How do i remove "Read more" using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i display : none "Read more" from the parent div class name "post-content" There is an issue , i am unable to remove the "Read More" through `<a>` tag class with the help of Jquery, how can i sort out this issue?
[Output of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3nTu.png)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="post-content">
      Wedding Season - frst one Paper Water Colour And Ink 17.5" x 23.5" <a href="http://bibihajra.com/wedding-season/" class="more-link">Read More</a>
    </div>
    <div class="post-content">
      Wedding Seassssssssssson - Third one Water Colour And Ink On Paper 17.5" x Weddiaaasasd23.5" <a href="http://bibihajra.com/wedding-season/" class="more-link">Read More</a>
    </div>
    <div class="post-content">
      Wedasaswqeqweqweqweqwqeqweson - Fouth one ater Colour And Ink On Paper 17.5" x 23.Weddiaaasasd" <a href="http://bibihajra.com/wedding-season/" class="more-link">Read More</a>
    </div>

  </body>

  </html>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('.post-content').text(function(_, txt) {
      return $.trim(txt.split('-').pop());
    });
    $(".more-link").css("display", "none");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Same thing as your dupe which I think you deleted.... You replace the element... The text line as I told you removes the element you are trying to remove.... So you need to select only the text, not the link or remove the link before you read the text.

Comment: You are creating the wrong HTML structure. `html` tag within the `html` tag is not allowed.

Comment: How many times are you going to ask this before you use an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should remove all elements by given class name:

```js
let links = document.querySelectorAll(".more-link");
for (let link of links) {
  link.remove();
}
```

```html
<div class="post-content">
  Wedding Season - frst one Paper <a href="" class="more-link">Read More</a>
</div>
<div class="post-content">
  Wedding Season - frst one Paper <a href="" class="more-link">Read More</a>
</div>
<div class="post-content">
  Wedding Season - frst one Paper <a href="" class="more-link">Read More</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `document.querySelectorAll` to get all the `a` elements that are that are descendants of `post-content` class div.

Next convert the `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll` to an `Array` by calling `Array.from` and passing the `NodeList` as the argument.

Finally, use `Array.protoype.forEach` to iterate over the elements and set the `display` property to `none`

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.post-content a')).forEach(anchorEl => anchorEl.style.display = 'none');
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="post-content">
    Wedding Season - frst one Paper Water Colour And Ink 17.5" x 23.5" <a href="http://bibihajra.com/wedding-season/" class="more-link">Read More</a>
  </div>
  <div class="post-content">
    Wedding Seassssssssssson - Third one Water Colour And Ink On Paper 17.5" x Weddiaaasasd23.5" <a href="http://bibihajra.com/wedding-season/" class="more-link">Read More</a>
  </div>
  <div class="post-content">
    Wedasaswqeqweqweqweqwqeqweson - Fouth one ater Colour And Ink On Paper 17.5" x 23.Weddiaaasasd" <a href="http://bibihajra.com/wedding-season/" class="more-link">Read More</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
$('.post-content').text(function(_, txt) {
  return $.trim(txt.split('-').pop());
});
```

Replaces the html in the `div` with text.  The "Read More" is now not a link but just the words.  So when you are trying to hide the links, the words are not wrapped with tag anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this. and please remove multiple body and html close tag. -

```js
$(".more-link").remove();
$('.post-content').text(function(_, txt) {
  return $.trim(txt.split('-').pop());
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="post-content">
      Wedding Season - frst one Paper Water Colour And Ink 17.5" x 23.5" <a href="http://bibihajra.com/wedding-season/" class="more-link">Read More</a>
    </div>
    <div class="post-content">
      Wedding Seassssssssssson - Third one Water Colour And Ink On Paper 17.5" x Weddiaaasasd23.5" <a href="http://bibihajra.com/wedding-season/" class="more-link">Read More</a>
    </div>
    <div class="post-content">
      Wedasaswqeqweqweqweqwqeqweson - Fouth one ater Colour And Ink On Paper 17.5" x 23.Weddiaaasasd" <a href="http://bibihajra.com/wedding-season/" class="more-link">Read More</a>
    </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an error with your initial method on .post-content, if you remove that:

$('.post-content a').hide(); works, which is what I'd use in this case.

What exactly are you trying to achieve with the first function? And why do you have body in a body, etc? That could also be causing issues.